# Method References to Super Class Method

Tags: kotlin, super, method-reference

How to use method references to refer to super class methods?

In Java 8 you can do `SubClass.super::method`.

What would be the syntax in Kotlin?

Looking forward to your response!

<s>**Conclusion**</s>

Thanks to Bernard Rocha!
The syntax is `SubClass::method`.

But be careful. In my case the subclass was a generic class. Don't forget to declare it as those:

`MySubMap<K, V>::method`.

**EDIT**

It still doesn't work in Kotlin.

Hers's an example in Java 8 of a method reference to a super class method:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    void method() { 
        System.out.println("superclass method()");
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    void method() {
        Runnable superMethodL = () -> super.method();
        Runnable superMethodMR = SubClass.super::method;
    }
}
```

I'm still not able to do the same in Kotlin...

**EDIT**

This is an example how I tried to achieve it in Kotlin:

```
open class Bar {
    open fun getString(): String = "Hello"
}

class Foo : Bar() {

    fun testFunction(action: () -> String): String = action()

    override fun getString(): String {
        //this will throw an StackOverflow error, since it will continuously call 'Foo.getString()'
        return testFunction(this::getString)
    }
}
```

I want to have something like that:

```
...
    override fun getString(): String {
        //this should call 'Bar.getString' only once. No StackOverflow error should happen.
        return testFunction(super::getString)
    }
...
```

**Conclusion**

It's not possible to do so in Kotlin yet.

I submitted a feature report. It can be found here: [KT-21103 Method Reference to Super Class Method](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21103)

Comment: Can you show us how you are trying to do this in Kotlin?

Comment: @BernardoRocha Sure. I added an example to my question.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation says](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) you use it like in java:

> If we need to use a member of a class, or an extension function, it
>   needs to be qualified. e.g. String::toCharArray gives us an extension
>   function for type String: String.() -> CharArray.

**EDIT**

I think you can achieve what you want doing something like this:

```
open class SuperClass {
    companion object {
        fun getMyString(): String {
            return "Hello"
        }
    }
}

class SubClass : SuperClass() {
    fun getMyAwesomeString(): String {
        val reference = SuperClass.Companion
        return testFunction(reference::getMyString)
    }

    private fun testFunction(s: KFunction0<String>): String {
        return s.invoke()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it is possible to get the reference to super class's function, but here is an alternative to what you want to achieve:

```
override fun getString(): String = testFunction { super.getString() }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Bernardo's answer, you might have something like this. It doesn't have remarkable changes.

```
fun methodInActivity() {
    runOnUiThread(this::config)
}

fun config(){

}
```

What is more, in the incoming 1.2 version you can use just

```
::config
```